# How to return to main and not the function calling it?

Tags: c, function, control-flow, setjmp

I have a `function()` which calls `anotherFunction()`.
Inside `anotherFunction()`, there is an `if` statement which, when satisfied returns back to `main()` and not to `function()`. How do you do this?

Comment: @mafso: Ahh, you're right.  The standard talks about "the initial call to `main()`" implying there can be others.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do like that in "standard" C. You can achieve it with [setjmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/setjmp) and [longjmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/longjmp) but it's strongly discouraged.

Why don't just return a value from `anotherFuntion()` and return based on that value? Something like this

```
int anotherFunction()
{
    // ...
    if (some_condition)
        return 1; // return to main
    else
        return 0; // continue executing function()
}

void function()
{
    // ...
    int r = anotherFuntion();
    if (r)
        return;
    // ...
}
```

You can return `_Bool` or return through a pointer if the function has already been used to return something else

Comment: @Bathsheba it may be useful in some situations but not in this case because there are easier and safer solutions

Comment: Both setjmp and longjmp are standard C as you have even referenced them.

Answer (score 2):

You can bypass the normal return sequence in C with the setjmp and longjmp functions.

They have an example at Wikipedia:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

static jmp_buf buf;

void second(void) {
    printf("second\n");         // prints
    longjmp(buf,1);             // jumps back to where setjmp was called - making setjmp now return 1
}

void first(void) {
    second();
    printf("first\n");          // does not print
}

int main() {   
    if ( ! setjmp(buf) ) {
        first();                // when executed, setjmp returns 0
    } else {                    // when longjmp jumps back, setjmp returns 1
        printf("main\n");       // prints
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily do that in C. Your best bet is to return a status code from `anotherFunction()` and deal with that appropriately in `function()`.

(In C++ you can effectively achieve what you want using exceptions).

Comment: This is incorrect. The standard setjmp and longjmp provide exactly this functionality.

Comment: I guess it's down to *easily*. I dislike having to store the buffer. I really wouldn't recommend it and stand by my recommendation of using return codes.

Answer (score 2):

Most languages have *exceptions* which enable this sort of flow control.  C doesn't, but it does have the `setjmp`/`longjmp` library functions which do this.